# How to update category attribute in magento?

Tags: magento

I have created a category attribute called "Filter" in Catelog--Category:

```
<?php
$this->startSetup();
$this->addAttribute(Mage_Catalog_Model_Category::ENTITY, 'filter', array(
    'group'         => 'General Information',
    'input'         => 'select',
    'type'          => 'varchar',
    'label'         => 'Filter',
    'backend'       => '',
    'visible'       => true,
    'required'      => false,
    'visible_on_front' => true,
    'global'        => Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Eav_Attribute::SCOPE_GLOBAL,
    ));
$this->endSetup();
```

And now I want to add "Yes/No" into this attribute, I searched online and tried to write some code, but they aren't working:

```
<?php
$add = $this->getEntityTypedId('catalog_category');
$this->updateAttribute($add, 'Filter', array(
    'option'        =>array('value' => array('optionone' => array('Yes'),
                                             'optiontwo' => array('No'),
                                            )
                            )
                                            )
                    );
```

Please give me some hints, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Use source models

```
$this->startSetup();
$this->addAttribute(Mage_Catalog_Model_Category::ENTITY, 'filter', array(
    'group'         => 'General Information',
    'input'         => 'select',
    'type'          => 'varchar',
    'label'         => 'Filter',
'backend'       => '',
'visible'       => true,
'required'      => false,
'visible_on_front' => true,
'global'        => Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Eav_Attribute::SCOPE_GLOBAL,
 'source'        => 'artic_filter/filter',
));

$this->endSetup();
```

Now create a class.

> ```
> class Namespace_Module_Model_Source_Filter extends   Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Attribute_Source_Table {
> ```
>
> public function getAllOptions()
>       {
>       return array(
>        'optionone' =>'Option One',
>       'optiontwo' =>'Option Two'
>       )
>       }
>       }

Update: 
add this in your global tag of xml

```
 <models>
            <arctic_filter>
                <class>Arctic_Filter_Model</class>
            </arctic_filter>
        </models>
```

Comment: Since I am new of magento, I have some question about your answer. For the 'source' part, it's the path of the created class, "Namespace_Module_Model_Source_Filter", and the file name is "source_filter" which I can modify it, am I right? Thanks!

Comment: I have tried following your answer, but there is no change on back-end.     I add "'source' =>'Filter_Model/updateFilter'," into install script, and create class like this: <?php
class Arctic_Model_Source_Filter extends Mage_Eav_Entity_Attribute_Source_Table
{
 public function getAllOptions()
 {
  return array('optionone'=>'Yes', 'optiontwo'=>'No');
 }}

Comment: please paste your config file

Comment: <?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
<modules>
<Arctic_Filter>
<version>0.0.1</version>
</Arctic_Filter>
</modules>
<global>
<resources>
<add_category_attribute>
<setup>
<module>Arctic_Filter</module>
<class>Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Setup</class>
</setup>
<connection>
<use>core_setup</use>
</connection>
</add_category_attribute>
<add_category_attribute_write>
<connection>
<use>core_write</use>
</connection>   
</add_category_attribute_write>
<add_category_attribute_read>
<connection>
<use>core_read</use>
</connection>   
</add_category_attribute_read>
</resources>
</global>
</config>

Comment: It seems no update there. :-/ I searched online and I found that once the category attribute created, there is no use to modify the install file. I have to create another .php file called "upgrade-x.x.x-x.x.x.php", is that true?